# TeamCity for static site

Tags: css, git, deployment, ant, teamcity

I am a front-end developer. I do a lot of PHPs/CSS/JS and HTMLs. Currently, how we do our deployment to staging environment is to push our codes to GIT servers. Go to our staging servers and do a pull to some directory. And then manually move the files from the directory to the correct directories in our apache web server.

Will it be overkill if I use TeamCity to do this? I intend to write an ANT script that does the copying which means to say Runner type will be ANT. So every time there is a push to the GIT repo, Teamcity will pull and then run the ANT script to copy the affected codes to the correct directories.

If not, I will gladly love to listen to any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: If your company already has a CI server, just use it. If your company is using github.com, you can enable "service hooks" to notify the CI server that there is a git push, instead of letting the CI to check the git server.

Comment: My company run it's own GIT server

Answer (score 1):

Teamcity may be overkill right now, as you would just be using it as a fancy trigger for your build.

But consider adding custom build parameters, which it can pass to your script. You can then start automating builds to different environments through a friendly UI.

You then have a platform to base a correct deployment process around further down the road.

Come the time when you need PHP compilation, JS minifcation, unit testing, its all just another step in your TC configuration.

I would recommend it.